# How to match version name later than 1.1.7? (or any version that I want)

Tags: regex, version

I'm using Firebase Remote Config and with my current setup, the only way to make the config only released to user with correct version is by using regex.

I'm looking for a regex that match any version released later than A.B.C

So if new version is x.y.z then the following must be true for it to match:

(x > A) or {(x = A) and [(y > B) or ((y = B) and (z > C))]}

Real number example:

Match any version equal to or later than 1.1.7:

Match:

```
1.1.7
1.1.8
1.1.69
1.2.0
1.10.0
2.0.0
```

Don't match:

```
1.1.6
1.0.34
0.5.0
0.77.0
```

I have tried this regex: `^(([2-9]|[0-9]{2,}).*|1\.(([0-9]{2,}).*|[1-9]\.([0-9]{3,}|[0-9]{2,}|[7-9])))` but it doesn't match 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?:1\.(?:1\.(?:[789]|[1-9]\d+)|(?:[1-9]\d+|[2-9])\.\d+)|(?:[1-9]\d+|[2-9])\.\d+\.\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZkX8s/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `1\.` Match `1.`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `1\.` Match `1.`
    - `(?:[789]|[1-9]\d+)` Match either `7` `8` `9` or 10+
    - `|` Or
    - `(?:[1-9]\d+|[2-9])` 10+ or 2-9
    - `\.\d+` Match `.` and 1+ digits 0-9
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[1-9]\d+` 10+
    - `|` Or
    - `[2-9]` Match 2-9
  - `)` Close non capture grouop
  - `\.\d+\.\d+`  Match `.` 1+ digits `.` 1+ digits
- `)` Close outer non capture group
- `$` End of string

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If in the future when I update my app to v1.0.4, v1.3.0 etc... How do I write my own Regex for the new version number? Do you have any tips?

Comment: @TrongNguyen A regex can not count using numbers, so for all the parts in the version number you have to check what the possible ranges are. In my answer, I first check the `1.1.range_here` part, then the `1.` followed by either 2-9 or greater than 10 part etc.. For single ranges, you can use a  regex range generator which can be found on SO  and other places online>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

`^([2-9]|1\d|1\.([2-9]|1\d|1\.([7-9]|\d\d)))`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/tO4xRe/1)

Comment: This only match the "1.2" part of the "1.2.0". I don't know exactly how Firebase regex check work but don't you need to match the whole version name string for it work?